# LINQ-query with if-statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with approx. 120,000 objects. From this list I want to extract data to create Person och Subscription objects. Logic is that 1 Person can have 1 or more newspaper subscriptions.

Im struggling how to write a Linq-query that only adds a new Person object if it has not already been created. In pseudo-like code something like this:

```
persons.Select(x => 

if (PersonIsAdded(x)) 
{
    var person = GetPerson(x);
    person.Address = "XXX";
    person.SubscriptionList.Add{new subscription() {Name = "newspaperName}
}
else
{
    new Person{ Address = "XYZ", SubscriptionList.Add{new subscription() {Name =     
    "newspaperName"} }
).ToList();
```

Comment: This isn't the way to create these objects. You need a `GroupBy` and create the whole lot in a single query. Can you show the rest of the code pelase so that we can give you a good solution?

Comment: It would also be great if you posted actual valid C# code. Something that we can work with with little effort.

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be LinQ? Can you build a `foreach` loop first? It will definitely be better for your understanding than copying a LinQ statement.

Comment: Is the actually a LINQ question or about how to make a lambda that includes if/else or other statement structures?

Comment: You can GROUP BY person , and it will be IGrouping<Person, List<Subscriptions>> in return

Comment: @ Enigmativity OK. I added the code above.

Comment: @Kran - Don't put a space after the `@` - the notifications don't work then.

Comment: @Kran - The code you added makes things worse. There's no `PersonIsAdded` method or `GetPerson`. I was hoping to simplify down your code, but that `ObjectMapper` is way too complicated.

Comment: @Kran - You need to read [ask].

Comment: (1) Are you using Entity Framework? There is an EF method to do exactly what you want but your question leaves it open as to what ORM you're using. (2) Is this a one-to-many mapping? Because I'd expect a many-to-many here (one person can have many subscriptions, one newspaper can have many subscribers)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you could do something like

```
var person = persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == yourId);

if (person == null)
{
  // create new person with subscription
}
else
{
    person.SubscriptionList.Add(subscription)
}
```

this is assuming you have an identifier for your person object

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've shown us (ignoring the complicated `ObjectMapper`) then I suggest that your code could look like this:

```
persons.Select(x =>
{
    if (PersonIsAdded(x))
    {
        var person = GetPerson(x);
        person.Address = "XXX";
        person.SubscriptionList.Add(
            new subscription() { Name = "newspaperName " });
        return person;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            Address = "XYZ",
            SubscriptionList = new []
            {
                new subscription() { Name = "newspaperName" }
            }.ToList(),
        }
    }
}).ToList();
```

However, that just seems wrong. Your code should be able to be something as simple as this:

```
List<Person> query =
(
    from x in persons
    join n in subscriptions on x equals n.Id into subs
    select new Person()
    {
        Address = x.Address,
        SubscriptionList =
            subs
                .Select(y => new subscription() { Name = n.Name })
                .ToList(),
    }
).ToList();
```

But you haven't given us the right amount of detail to be sure that this is correct or not.

Comment: The first example I gave was, as I wrote, pseudo code. I dont want to create a person object for each object in persons. I only want to create a person object if it has not been added before. I think group by statement can be helpful here.

Comment: @Kran - The question was tagged as C# - not use pseudo-code unless you are very clear that that was your intent. However, that will reduce the number of people who try to answer.